# ESP-01S: Problem waking up from deep sleep

Tags: arduino, sleep, esp8266

I'm trying to program modules with ESP8266 chip using Arduino IDE. So far, I have tried the ESP-01 module and I am just trying to program the ESP-01S. I came across a problem with this module waking up from deep sleep mode. I have this simple code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

void setup () {
   Serial.begin (74880);
   Serial.println ("Test");
   ESP.deepSleep (60 * 1e6);
}

void loop () {
}
```

Of course I have GPIO16 connected to the RST pin. When the power supply is connected, the program starts and the text "TEST" is displayed in the console. Then the module sleeps for 60 seconds. After waking up, a message will appear and this will end:

```
ets Jan 8 2013, rst cause: 2, boot mode: (3,6)
```

I have tested this code on ESP-01 and it works. Would anyone please advise me where the problem might be?

Comment: Try to change the `Serial.println()` to a blink LED or something, the Serial take quite some time to initialise and your `Serial.println()` is printed before the Serial is ready. Alternatively add a `delay(1000)` before the `Serial.println()`.

Comment: Also add a `delay(50)` before the `ESP.deepSleep()` to let the `Serial.println()` before it go back to sleep.

Comment: I tried the code modifications you mentioned, but the result is still the same ...
I tried to measure the reset pulse that comes from GPIO16 and I can say that there will probably be a problem. The classic ESP-01 board has a beautiful rectangular pulse that lasts about 200 us. With this ESP-01S board, the pulse is not rectangular, but pointed and very short approx. 100 us. Is it possible that the chip is defective? I have 2 such boards and both show the same problem.

Comment: The voltage on the RST pin drops to only 1 V.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 12k resistor between VDD3V3 and RST on the board. (page 17 of the [schematic](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/ESP-01S_C82893.pdf)). That is fighting with your GPIO16 and leaving 1V. In my case I had a 10K resistor between GPIO16 and RST and was left with 1.8V. By removing the 12K on-board resistor, deep sleep should work. On the top of the board there is a row with 3 capacitors on the left side, the resistor next to those is the one to remove.